# SPSS save decimal number to ASCII

Tags: spss

I am trying to save a numeric-with-decimal-places(f8.6) variable from an SPSS file into a fixed ASCII file. The goal is to write it into certain columns of the ASCII (21 to 30).

```
    WRITE OUTFILE='C:\misc\ascii.dat'
      ENCODING='UTF8'
      TABLE /1
    variable 21-30.
exe.
```

writes to the correct positions, but not with decimals.

```
variable 21-30 (f)
```

does the same thing.

```
variable (f8.6)
```

saves with decimals, but on positions 1 to 10.

```
variable 21-30 (f8.6)
```

results in an error, because apparently you cannot specify both columns and format.

I know two workarounds, but both involve additional data editing, which I'd rather not do:

1. Convert variable to string and save it as string - but I am not sure about the implications (encoding, decimal places, or whatever other thing I am not even considering)
2. add an empty string variable with length of 20 before my variable.

But is there a straightforward way of doing this, without workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the 20 spaces in the command itself, like this:

```
WRITE OUTFILE='C:\misc\ascii.dat'
      ENCODING='UTF8'
      TABLE / '                    '  YourNumVar (f8.6) .
exe.
```

Comment: true, this is another workaround, which might become as inconvenient as the others if the columns where I need my variable will change. For example, if i need to write it on 151-160 or thousands :)

Comment: That's right, I see your point. Don't know a better way to do it myself - I vote for your workaround of adding an empty text variable before `YourNumVar`.